# Moving all files with same file extension .txt to a new directory

Tags: command-line, files, directory, mv, recursive

Basically, my hard drive is a mess and I have like 200+ sub-directories in a main directory. I want to essentially move all files in 200+ sub-directories that have the extension `.txt` etc to a new directory. For example, `n00b.txt` or `n00b.txt.exe`

So I try the following command in the main directory consisting of the 200+ subdirectories `sudo mv **/*.txt  ~/Desktop/tmpremo/`

Instead I am getting this error: `bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Argument list too long`

Why am I getting it and how do I remove say `.txt,.txt.exe`? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would move all files with `.txt` and `.txt.exe` extensions present anywhere inside the current directory (even in subdirectories) to `~/Desktop/tmpremo`.

```
$ sudo find . -type f \( -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.txt.exe' \) -exec mv {} ~/Desktop/tmpremo \;
```

If you want another extension too, just add `-o -iname '*.extension'` before the `-exec`.

PS: As @xenoid noted, please refrain from using `sudo` unless it is absolutely required for the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks so much SIr! Worked like a charm so I accepted answer!!

Comment: The two `-iname` tests needs to be grouped as `\( -iname ... -o -iname ... \)`.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks! (But seriously, I don't see anyone creating directories or special files with `.txt` or `.txt.exe` in their names).

Answer (score 1):

(newbie here so I can't comment @BarBar1234's answer)

I believe there's no need to echo the output of 'find', as the command itself already echoes the founded filenames.

So instead you could just use:

```bsh
sudo find . -type f -iname '*.txt'
```

But, for the sake of knowledge, the outputs you were getting (`find: ‘echo ./rdggt_169/frretcdd_td.txt ’: No such file or directory`) happens because in the command

```bsh
sudo find . -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec 'echo {}'  \;
```

the part that says `-exec 'echo {}'` is giving a single-quoted argument to `-exec`, therefore, it treats the whole expanded string as a command.

To be clear, the string 'echo foo/bar.txt' is not the command `echo` with a 'foo/bar.txt' argument, that's why nothing was found in your system, because no command exists in your system with the name `echo foo/bar.txt`.

That's why BarBar1234 just edited the answer, removing the single quotes. Now `echo` is treated as what is supposed to be treated in this case, a command, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `**/*.txt` is expanded with all the matching files (with full paths) as a very long command line, and there is a limit to the length to the arguments.

A problem with using `find ... -exec mv` is that you run `mv` once for each file.

There is a command that will attempt to run commands with the maximum allowed number of arguments: `xargs`, so you just need to pipe the output of `find` to `xargs` and tell `xargs` to run `mv` (arguments are by default appended at the end):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ~/Desktop/tmpremo
```

PS: I'm surprised that you have to use `sudo` to move files inside your own user directories.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using `**`, why not do a simple loop?

```bash
for name in ./**/*.txt ./**/*.txt.exe; do
    mv "$name" "$HOME/Desktop/tmpremo"
done
```

The `Argument list too long` error is due to the shell trying to execute a command with too many/long arguments.  This is a limitation in one of the `exec()` family of C library functions, which has a restriction on the sum of the length of the arguments and the combined size of all environment variables (on Linux, it's slightly more complicated with each argument having a maximum allowed length too I believe, but that's details).

---

I can see from your error message that you are using `bash`, but if you were a `zsh` user and had GNU `mv`, you could instead do

```sh
autoload -U zargs
zargs -- ./**/*.txt(.) ./**/*.txt.exe(.) -- mv -t "$HOME/Desktop/tmpremo"
```

The `zargs` utility is a bit like `xargs`, but implemented as a loadable `zsh` shell function.  See `zargs --help` ofter loading it, and the `zshcontrib(1)` manual.

Answer (score 0):

try this from the **top level directory** where the subdirectories are located:

```bsh
sudo find . -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec echo {}  \;
```

and if the list of files found shows a list of text files in question, do:

```bsh
sudo find . -path ~/Desktop/tmpremo -prune -o -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec mv {} ~/Desktop/tmpremo/ \;
```

Comment: thanks for replying sir. i tried the first command and for some strange reason or another I am getting a load of this `find: ‘echo ./rdggt_169/frretcdd_td.txt ’: No such file or directory` I can see it in directories though

Comment: I corrected the commands, the `'` around `exec` commands were not necessary.